# parallelize nested loop in OpenMP and do inner loop with more thread

Tags: c++, c, performance, openmp

I have this kind of nested loop : I want to know how can I parallelize this in best form in which :

1. Second and third `for` and also fifth and sixth `for` run at the same
       time
2. First and fourth `for` in serial

If I have 24 core and want to divide outer for between 16 thread and use rest of them to execute inner `for` with them , for example execute second `for` with 8 thread not only one thread , what should I do ?

```
void main()
{
//first_for
   for(int y=0; y< height; y++)
{
      //second_for 
      for(int x=0; x< width-1; x++)
   {
     func1();
   }
      //third_for
      for(int x=0; x< width-1; x++)
   {
     func2();
   }

}
//fourth_for
   for(int x=0; x<width; x++)
{
     //fifth_for
     for(int y=0; y< height-1; y++)
   {
     func3();
   }
     //sixth_for
     for(int y=0; y< height-1; y++)
   {
     func4();
   }
}
}
```

Comment: but does the first and the fourth run concurrently with the 4 others?

Comment: first first_for and after that fourth_for ? what does the best treatment  with nested loop in OpenMP?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding nested parallelism with OpenMP.  If you run an outer loop across 16 threads and request 8 threads within that scope you will get (provided that your implementation supports nested parallelism) `16*8==128` threads in total; that is, each of the outer 16 threads gets 8 inner threads.  On a 24 core machine this is probably always going to be a bad idea as the threads contend for access to processor cores, as they each trash the others cache, etc.

Comment: yes @Mark you are right Mark , and what about using sections directive in the for doing two inner for in parallel , I have noticed about your point but I want to execute both of these two for at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Regarding parallelism introduction, it's common to say that the coarser level is better, so if you can add parallel directive at a coarse level that scale well why would you also add  nested parallelism ?

so based on what can be run concurrently i would write the main like that:

```
int main()
{
     //first_for
     #pragma parallel for
     for(int y=0; y< height; y++)
     {
          //second_for and third_for
      for(int x=0; x< width-1; x++)
     {
          func1();
          func2();

      }
  }
 //fourth_for
 #pragma parallel for
 for(int x=0; x<width; x++)
 {
      //fifth_for and  //sixth_for
     for(int y=0; y< height-1; y++)
    {
          func3();
          func4();
     }
  }
 return 0;
}
```

1. we increase the work to do per line and per column by merging the 2 inner loop
2. we add openMP directive to split that computational loop in smaller chunk depending of your number of core.
3. See if you can invert the first loop because depending of what you do inside and how your "image" is mapped in memory, treating column first may lead to a lot of caching error....

EDIT

you can enable nested parallelism, but it goes in wrong way, too much loop and thread accessing to different chunck of memory will just decrease performance and you also will also have a solution designed for 24 core that may not scale with 32, 48 core etc... But if you insist you have to set an env variable or call an openMP function:

```
 call omp_set_nested()
 or
 set OMP_NESTED=TRUE|FALSE
```

after add an openMP clause on your top level loop to specify specify the chunck size you want in order to only have X thread.

```
int  chunckSize = height / X;
#pragma parallel for schedule ( static , chunckSize)
```

the openMP thread team should be compose of 24 thread, but by doing this only X will have work to do. Follow that logic for nested loop.

But it's not the solution I recommend!

Comment: I want to know is this the best form ? and what about this question? If I have 24 core and want to divide outer for between 16 thread and use rest of them to execute inner for with them , for example execute second for with 8 thread not only one thread , what should I do ?

Comment: I edited my answer, but the way you go will lead to strange behavior, more synchronization point (join), etc, etc...,

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has been said, you may want to explicitly enable nested parallelism. It is possible to do so with either a library call at run-time or an environment variable (for OpenMP).

For more information, check out this [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5270/aewbc/index.html).